# How to add row to top of a table in java

Tags: java, list, jsp, row

I am using java to add rows to the table. Currently I am able to add the row to the table but at the end of the list using the following code:

```
List list = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
DetailsMod mod = new DetailsMod();
list.add(mod);
```

if I were to change the last line to:

```
list.add(0, mod);
```

it will only add the first column to the top of the table while the rest of the columns remain at the bottom of the table.

the html looks smth like this:

```
<% 
List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
DetailsMod bean = new DetailsMod();
    if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
      for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
         bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
%>
<tr>                
   <td height="17">
      <input name="tbx_A<%=i%>"value="<%=bean.getA()%>" readonly/>
   </td>
   <td height="17">
      <input name="tbx_B<%=i%>" value="<%=bean.getB()%>" />
   </td>
</tr>
<% }
}%>
```

So yeah... How do I add the entire row to the top of the table?
Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Comment: What kind of table is this? A swing table?

Comment: @tbodt It's just a normal table. hopefully the edit version helps. Thnks

Comment: On behalf of @junkiecoder: Please explain your question more clearly!

Comment: @tbodt still not clear enuf? how shall I put it? the top part is from servlet. the jsp is taking in the data from servlet to be displayed. its just a normal table u know with <table><tr><td> kinda format? so yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to add the particular row in the particular index.

- add a new value at any point.
- set a new value at that point.

Comment: is there an example on the usage of ListIterator that I can look at? and anyways Thnks for earlier!

Comment: Try this .. ListIterator listIterator = list.listIterator();
        
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            if(listIterator.nextIndex() == 0)
            {
                listIterator.add(mod);
            }
            break;
        }

Comment: Thnks! I tried it bt it adds to the bottom(next) row instead of the first row. is there any other way to counter this? thnks!